# Why doesn't the docker volume in Windows Server show up when I run this command?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I have a folder setup on the host machine at c:\testvol.
The docker image does not have a folder at c:\testvol.

When I run:

```
docker run --rm -d --name {name} {imagename} --v c:\testvol:c:\testvol
```

Why doesn't the volume show up on the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears in the docker command you need to specify the image name as the last parameter unless you want to pass arguments to be processed by the docker file.

Also, --v should be -v or --volume as --v is not recognized by the docker command.

The command you want is:

```
docker run --rm -d --name {name} --volume c:\testvol:c:\testvol {imagename}
```